# URL redirect issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using wordpress for my blog. Url ends with "/" is working fine. But without the "/" its not working, showing page not found. I am using permalinks postname. Below is the htaccess redirect rule.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

For example: **www.test.com/blog/** is working. But **www.test.com/blog** this url is not working, It showing page not found.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: So, According to your .htaccess ur wordpress Installation is in blog directory right?

Comment: @PranavBhatt yes

Comment: You should try.
define('WP_HOME','http://pressable.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://pressable.com/blog');

Comment: @PranavBhatt I tried this. But its not working

Comment: Go To wp-admin > Settings > Permalinks and set according to your desire.

Comment: your .htaccess code is right you need to make your permalinks first default then make it postname again